# Getting all Azure backup from recovery vault across all subscriptions

Tags: azure, powershell, for-loop

I am trying to use powershell to generate a CSV report to show all backup items in all recovery vaults across all Azure subscriptions.

```
 ForEach ($Subscription in $Subscriptions) {
             $RCvaults = get-azrecoveryservicesvault
                  ForEach ($RCvault in $RCvaults) {
                            get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupJob
    }
 }
```

However, it seems I am only getting backup information of one VM.   Also, I am not too sure how to export to CSV.  I'm new to Powershell, any help would be appreciated

Comment: you are looping through your subscriptions but you are not switching the context to the subscription so everyloop will just get the same recovery vault. You need to use Set-AzContext to switch subscription in the first foreach. You also need to set the Vault Context by using Set-AzRecoveryServicesVaultContext inside the second foreeach.

Comment: to export your data to a CSV look into the Export-CSV command. You need to store all data to one variable then you can after the loop just pipe the variable to Export-CSV.

Comment: Or as an alternative you can just go to one of the Recovery Vaults in the portal and on the overview you have a link to "Backup Explorer" this is a tool to consolidate all information regarding backups on your subscriptions to one place. Here you have a download button that will give you the CSV file. :)

Comment: would you be able to provide a more detailed script?  I have been struggling to put these together....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.

```
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

ForEach ($Subscription in $Subscriptions) {
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $Subscription.Id

    $RCvaults = get-azrecoveryservicesvault
    
    ForEach ($RCvault in $RCvaults) 
    {
        Set-AzRecoveryServicesVaultContext -Vault $RCvault
        Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupJob
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much.  I tested this out in Azure automation runbook, but it seems the line Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $Subscription.Id    is printing out all the subscription details like Nmae, Account, Environment, Teanant, Token Cache etc.   Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: @Headandtoes yes thats the default behavior when changing context, it will print the context you changed to. If you dont want it to output anything then you can just assign it to a variable:     $sub = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $Subscription.Id